# "null is not an object" in n.parentNode.removeChild expression

Tags: javascript, exception, web-applications, sentry

**Problem:**
I'm getting following error reports from the webpage on production:

```
TypeErrores6-shim/es6-shim in process
null is not an object (evaluating 'n.parentNode.removeChild')
```

**Question**

On the low level, what is the most likely scenario?

1. `n` is `null` (whatever `n` is)
2. `n.parentNode` is `null`
3. `arg` is `null` in `n.parentNode.removeChild(arg)`

**More details (if relevant):**

We're using Sentry error reporting system to report errors.

This error happens under Mobile Safari and Chrome Mobile.

The source maps seems to be broken so I don't know which line of es6-shim script the error refers to (and most likely it's es6-shim problem at all as there is no occurence of removeChild in es6-shim code).

Comment: Put in some debug code to see what *n* is just before the call. The only element with a *null* parentNode is the document itself. If *arg* was null I'd expect a different error like "*arg must be a Node*" or similar.

Comment: @RobG: Any element you haven't added to the DOM (or have since removed) also has a `null` `parentNode`, e.g., `document.createElement("div").parentNode` is `null`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—yes, didn't think of that. Also I guess any node that's been removed from the DOM to which a reference has been kept.

Comment: @Piotr Sobczyk it will be helpful if you show some html and js code.

Comment: @AabirHussain the problem is that I don't know from where in my source code is the exception thrown. All that I have is error message reported from production server, with no exact place in the code. I have a few places with removeNode in my codebase + it may come from some external library.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set up all three situations to determine which it is ([also on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3022j4or/)):

```js
var n, p;

console.log("If n were null:")
try {
  n = null;
  n.parentNode.removeChild(null);
} catch (e1) {
  console.log(e1.message);
}

console.log("If parentNode were null:")
try {
  n = document.createElement("div");
  n.parentNode.removeChild(null);
} catch (e2) {
  console.log(e2.message);
}

console.log("If arg were null:")
try {
  p = document.createElement("div");
  n = document.createElement("div");
  p.appendChild(n);
  n.parentNode.removeChild(null);
} catch (e3) {
  console.log(e3.message);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

When I run that on mobile Chrome, I see:

```
If n were null:
null is not an object (evaluating 'n.parentNode')
If parentNode were null:
null is not an object (evaluating 'n.parentNode.removeChild')
If arg were null:
Argument 1 ('child') to Node.removeChild must be an instance of Node
```

So it would appear that `n.parentNode.removeChild(...)` is being called on an object referenced by `n` where `parentNode` is `null`.

Although the error is reported in es6-shim, it's not likely to be an error in es6-shim itself (as you say, there's no `removeNode` in es6-shim); it's more likely that it's being thrown from a callback provided to one of the es6-shim functions.

Comment: Very good answer. Some very useful info to help me with further debugging it! Thank you.